# How is #else 1 just a warning?

Tags: c, syntax, c-preprocessor

Clang has the following test cases:

```
#if 0
#ifdef D
#else 1       // Should not warn due to C99 6.10p4
#endif
#endif

#if 0
#else 1   // expected-warning {{extra tokens}}
#endif
```

The first `#else 1` indeed is fine  because it's in a skipped group, but as far as I can see the second one should be an error - it doesn't match what the standard specifies as the syntax for preprocessor directives - yet GCC and Microsoft C++ agree on only giving it a warning. What am I missing?

Comment: Microsofts C/C++ compiler is well known for allowing lots of this that is not entirely correct, according to the standards. I guess you have to live with it, or switch to a more stringent compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard does not have notions of "error" and "warning", it only knows "diagnostic". It is up to implementation to define what constitutes a diagnostic. Most implementations of C, including clang and gcc, define diagnostics to include both errors and warnings.

Comment: And gcc's `-pedantic-errors` option causes it to treat all language-required diagnostics as fatal errors.

Comment: And VC++ has the equivalent `/WX` option to treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: For that matter, gcc has the equivalent `-Werror` option to treat *all* warnings as errors. `-pedantic-errors` is for people who want to allow some warnings in their code, but want to reject code that's actually ill-formed. For example their code might contain dubious constructs like `if (a = b);` that break the style guide that gcc recommends, or less-dubious constructs that trigger other warnings they disagree with, but for whatever reason they don't want to have to disable/workaround the warning just to get a compile.